# Can´t load plist file, Error Failed to parse Plist data type:key

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, plist

I get the error from the title in my xamarin forms app. It doesn't have that error before I update VS2017. I did this because I need some libraries for unity (and load all the others related to games). Now I can't even load the iOS part in Xamarin Forms, it says is not available. This is my  Info.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key> 
<array> 
<integer>1</integer> 
<integer>2</integer> 
</array> 
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key> 
<array> 
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string> 
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string> 
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string> 
</array> 
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key> 
<array> 
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string> 
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string> 
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string> 
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string> 
</array> 
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key> 
<string>8.0</string> 
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key> 
<string>AppPosventa</string> 
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key> 
<string>com.companyname.AppPosventa</string> 
<key>CFBundleVersion</key> 
<string>1.0</string> 
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key> 
<string>LaunchScreen</string> 
<key>CFBundleName</key> 
<string>appPosventa</string> 
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key> 
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string> 
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
<string>fa-solid-900.ttf</string>
</array>
</dict> </plist>
```

Comment: sorry, I have windows, so I don't understand very well what is the error that signals plutil

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> plutil can be used to check the syntax of property list files, or convert a plist file
>        from one format to another.  Specifying - as an input file reads from stdin.

So pasting your plist into a file and running:

> plutil stackoverflow.plist

Results in:

```
stackoverflow.plist: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 41
```

Thus, you have no `string` value type assigned for your location key:

`<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>`

Comment: @GuillermoGómezSánchez you should mark it as answer