# Xamarin Forms.iOS Failed to parse PList data type

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store

Friens please help me when I publish my app to the App store I have face below error.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share us your info.plist? Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016758/can%C2%B4t-load-plist-file-error-failed-to-parse-plist-data-typekey) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed only version and code from info.plist and it's working for me